# How widely established are the laws against reporting on polling during election?

Tags: election, international, freedom-of-speech, polling

In comments on " [Is the "no poll reporting till voting is done" specific to Brexit vote?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11392/is-the-no-poll-reporting-till-voting-is-done-specific-to-brexit-vote?noredirect=1#comment38025_11392) " I was made aware that other countries also have rules against reporting on polling numbers on election day, and it's not a UK-only concept.

As such, I'm curious if there's a good estimate that exists on how the worldwide handling of this issue is broken down? Do most countries have such laws? Only a minority?

Comment: I tagged as [freedom-of-speech] because I suspect one reason to avoid such a law is on freedome of speech grounds. Not sure.

Comment: In Spain it is forbidden from a week before. But in later elections it has been circumvented by publishing news about, say, the prices of "goods" at some market (so you do not get the data that PP will get 120-126 seats, PSOE 90-92 seats, etc...,  but that the price of grapes is between 120-126€, that of oranges 90-92€, etc.) during that week. Anyway during election day I have still not seen any poll published (either openly or disguised) until the poll stations are closed.

Comment: any source? Wow.

Comment: I’m not sure how to find a source. However, the German WIkipedia article on election polling research (in Germany publishing polling numbers before polling stations close is also illegal) gives a short, random list of a few European countries that fit your classification and then proceeds to list the situation in Germany, Austria and Switzerland all of which have such laws.

Comment: This Wikipedia page is primarily about restrictions on campaigning but also lists restrictions on polling by nation (it's unlikely to be comprehensive): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Election_silence